# Getting the number of pages from a google document using google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I need to get the number of pages of a google document and have come across the following code

```
function getNumPages() {
  var blob = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getAs("application/pdf");
  var data = blob.getDataAsString();
  var pages = parseInt(data.match(/ \/N (\d+) /)[1], 10);
  Logger.log("pages = " + pages);
  return pages; 
}
```

when run however I get the following error on the 4th line

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null
```

when I log the data variable it outputs

```
%PDF-1.4
%����
1 0 obj
<</Title (Reddit_Fin)
/Producer (Skia/PDF m92 Google Docs Renderer)>>
endobj
3 0 obj
<</ca 1
/BM /Normal>>
endobj
5 0 obj
<</Filter /FlateDecode
/Length 548>> stream
x��UQk�0~ϯ��%[�
cp�}��lka�����s��H��]Y  H�>�>����!  ����ϐ-8�~�>��j�B�����>z��w�>p�9�yx���<�&J�d�Q2��K~
���fm|{���4�>���/1��
```

this is of a 8 page document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, in your situation, how about counting the number of `Contents`? I thought that when Google Document is converted to the PDF data by retrieving as the blob using Google Apps Script, this method can be used. When this is reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

##### From:

```
var pages = parseInt(data.match(/ \/N (\d+) /)[1], 10);
```

##### To:

```
var pages = data.match(/\/Contents/g).length;
```

and

```
var pages = [...data.matchAll(/\/Contents/g)].length;
```

#### Note:

- If above modification cannot be used, I thought that the external API like https://www.convertapi.com/ might be useful for directly achieving your goal.

#### References:

- [match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)
- [matchAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll)

Comment: Great! Thank you, Tanaike. But I dare to say, that the old version `var pages = parseInt(data.match(/ \/N (\d+) /)[1], 10);` worked well for me in 2020. Perhaps the sample is even copied from my snippet. And it doesn't work anymore indeed. Probably Google changed something, I don't know. `Contents` works fine, for now.

Comment: @Yuri Khristich Thank you for your additional information. About `var pages = parseInt(data.match(/ \/N (\d+) /)[1], 10);`, I couldn't know it. I apologize for this. From your comment, in the current stage, I understood that above script also worked in your environment. Thank you for checking it. But, also this method might not be able to be used in the future update at Google side. At that time, I think that it might be required to use the external API.